# React Native Android - Lifecycle methods

Tags: react-native

Ive found some very odd behavior in RN (Android).

I hit center/circle button to put app in background.....then I click the app icon to bring back to foreground and sometimes it runs constructor/componentdidmount etc and sometimes it doesnt??

If I use left/arrow button to exit app it always runs constructor....and if I use right/square button to bring it back, it never runs constructor.....but the center/circle button seems to vary based on ??.

Any ideas?  Very strange indeed

Answer (score 2):

as for first appearance when you use center/circle button to put the app in the background; if the time is long, the app is killed by the system, so it runs constructor/componentdidmount, if the time is short, it will not runs.

when you use the left/arrow button, the android native will execute it Activity lifecycle:`onPause-OnStop-OnDestory`, the React Native host Activity is destroyed, it always runs constructor.

you use right/square button to bring it back;  it is the same with the first appearance， the app is run in the background, so it never runs constructor

Comment: ...so are you saying that if app is running in background (it definitely is in background).....and you hit icon to bring back to foreground (instead of using right/square button).....it should not run constructor?  Thats the problem because thats whats happening

Comment: the android system will check the app if it is in the background for a long time, it will kill the app according to the process level. if the app is in the background and the component is also mount, it will not run the constructor. the react-native firstly depends on the native lifecycle, then it own lifecycle.

Comment: @james murphy, if you need to do something when every enter the component, you can change to use this. navigation lifecycle: `didFocus`,`didBlur`